# How to send command via python to running screen (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: python, linux, gnu-screen

I am on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS running Python 2.7. My Python code looks somewhat like this:

```
from os import system
system("screen -S session -X stuff 'commandhere'`echo -ne '\015'`")
```

But when I try to run it, it does not do anything. I was wondering whether it was possible to fix this, and if so, how?

I am trying to send a command to an active screen "session" where "commandhere" is the command.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS; Python 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["screen", "-S", "session", "-X", "stuff", "'command here'`echo -ne '\015'`"])
```

Another idea: It might be best to just create a `bash` script to do the session manipulation stuff and just have Python then call the `bash` script.

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't seem to accept the "-S session" part.  Specifically states "Error: Unknown option S session"

Comment: I am using the name of the actual running session (jcmp).

Comment: Could this be something with the python version?

Comment: it seems to be that it was an error in the call itself.  I will reference the answer to [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482419/python-subprocess-not-executing-properly/24482434#24482434)